# Mouse Cursor in Java

Tags: java, swing, cursor, jlist, acm-java-libraries

Could you tell me, Why it doesn't work. When I run it, mouse hides. but I want to change mouse cursor's icon.

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JList;

import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;

public class test1 extends GraphicsProgram {

    public Cursor stoneCursor;

    public void run() {
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image image = toolkit.getImage("cursor.gif");
        Point hotspot = new Point(0, 0);
        stoneCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotspot, "Stone");
        getContentPane().setCursor(stoneCursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post stacktrace, please?

Comment: I don't know What is stracktrace

Comment: Here is quick info for stacktrace - http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fconsole%2Fref-stacktrace_console.htm

Comment: The cursor will only appear when the mouse pointer is over the applet. Is the pointer over the applet?

Comment: Yes, it is over the applet

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example try this..

Standard Cursor Image:

```
setCursor (Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

User defined Image:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  Image image = toolkit.getImage("icons/handwriting.gif");
  Cursor c = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image , new Point(mainPane.getX(),
     mainPane.getY()), "img");
  mainPane.setCursor (c);
```

Comment: There is some problem with mainpane